# ADFS Cors configuration

Tags: adfs

is there any way to configure cors for an adfs on premise?

Seems like the only option is ssl termination on a loadbalancer and manual adding the needed headers to the response.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS supports federation protocols like SAML and WS-Fed.

Since CORS is not part of these protocols, it is not supported.

Comment: It also supports oauth!?